# How to change the DataTable's Column DataType which already has data using C#.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, datatable

I have two DataTables which has the following rows.

Table A:

```
  TaxID               TaxName
 ------              --------
   1                    VAT
   2                    Sales Tax
```

Table B:

```
 TaxID                TaxName
 -----                --------
   1A                  ED
   2A                  Discount
```

In Table A: The datatype for the column TaxID is INT
In Table B: The datatype for the column TaxID is String.

Now I want to merge these two tables.
I tried like this:
        TableA.Merge(TableB);
But it gives error.
how to achieve this?

Comment: please mention the error in the question

Comment: Change the datatype of column in Table A to varchar matching the one in Table B and then it will be merged properly..

Comment: Is `1A`=`1` the same records, so should `ED` replace `VAT` or not? Should TaxID be an int or a varchar column after merging?

Comment: @Vijay: How to change the datatype of the Column TaxID in Table A.

Comment: @Tim: No. Both are different. It should not replace. Only I want to merge. So totally the Datatable would have 4 rows.

Comment: @TheVan: You cannot change a DataColumn's DataType after the Datatable was populated with data. So you should cast it with SQL to the appropriate type(varchar) before you fill it.

Comment: @thevan you should change the datatype of columnn in the database table itself and then load the data in datatable..probably i think you wouldnt be allowed to change the datatype in DB table itself by permission..so go with the suggestion of Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change a DataColumn's DataType after the Datatable was populated with data. So you should cast it with SQL to the appropriate type(`varchar`) before you fill it.

For example:

```
SELECT CAST(TaxID as varchar(5))AS TaxID, TaxName FROM TableA
```